# Windows7: how to put an item in startup directory without Admin rights

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, boot, administrator

I share my work computer with 3 other employees. It would be very helpful to run a script at startup for all of us. It is a big company, and there is a lot of red tape for everything!!!

So, we were wondering if we could put in this item in Windows 7 Startup directory (without admin rights) so that it is executed at every startup.

I have wondered if I could boot the computer with some sort of live USB like Windows PE (BARTPE or Active@ Boot or maybe even Ubuntu Live) and put the script in the directory.

Would that work?

Update: I can't boot my computer with a USB or a CD because apparently I need (you guessed it right) the admin password to do that at the boot time.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer would be a yes, for your own startup folder.  You would need to do this for each person, so it is in each users profile.

However, depending on things like group policy, you may be locked down pretty tight.  A lot of that depends on the company, the programs that need to be run, and the rights that are needed by the user to run those programs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: is it not possible to put it in the general startup... so that the script runs on every login?

Comment: It will be in the C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu folder as opposed to the all users\startup folder (general name).  Does that help more?

Comment: So, if I just put the item in  `all users\startup` it is going to be run at login for any user logging in?

Comment: If this is Windows 7, you would have to put it in the Default user area, so when a new user logs in and the local profile created, that is part of it.  If the user profile is already created, then you need to do it individually as 1st stated.

Comment: I can't even boot my computer from a USB or a dvd! what other options do I have?

Comment: apparently I need an administrator password to change boot priority

Comment: Sorry man.  This is one of those situations where everything is locked down.  I worked for one company where you couldn't see anything unless they wanted you to.  Everything was done through group policy.  Unfortunately, there really isn't anything that you can do short of asking your tech people if they will place it ther for you.

Comment: there has to be a way :(